# x86 Video mode Clear Screen

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos, bios

Hello I'm trying to clear the screen in DOS video mode with this code.

But when I run it, the dot is still there!

```
    org 100h

    mov     ah, 0       ; set display mode function.
    mov     al, 13h     ; mode 13h = 640x480 pixels, 256 colors.
    int     10h         ; set it!

    mov     cx, 10      ; column
    mov     dx, 10      ; row
    mov     al, 15      ; white
    mov     ah, 0ch     ; put pixel
    int     10h         ; draw pixel

    ; -------  clear the screen ----------     
    ; -------  doesn't work! dot is still there

    mov ax,0B800h
    mov es,ax
    xor di,di
    xor ax,ax
    mov cx,2000d
    cld
    rep stosw

    ; -------------------------------------

    ;wait for keypress
    mov ah,00
    int 16h

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h

    ;======================================================
```

I tried resetting the video mode with INT 10 but this gives me blinks which is unwanted inside my loop

Comment: Mode 13h is 320x200 not 640x480 and the buffer is located at segment 0xa000, not 0xb800 and the buffer size is 32000 words not 2000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

First, BIOS mode 13h is not 640x480 at 8 bits/pixel, it's 320x200 at 8 bits/pixel.

B800h is the address of BIOS text modes. BIOS graphics modes use A000h.

So it should be:

```
mov ax,0A000h
mov es,ax
xor di, di     ; ES:0 is the start of the framebuffer
```

320x200 at 8 bits consumes 320*200 = 64 000 bytes of video memory. So the value of `cx` is incorrect. It should be:

```
mov cx,32000d    ; you can write 320 * 200/2 in your source if you want
cld
xor ax,ax
rep stosw        ; zero 2*CX bytes at ES:DI
```

Comment: s/16000/32000/ otherwise +1

Comment: @user786653 Fixed. I was thinking that in 32-bit DOS code I would do it `xor eax,eax; mov ecx,16000d; rep stosd` and then confused myself...

Comment: That explains a lot, it's so smooth now :D
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Note that you can do something like `mov cx,320*200/2` to make it easier to read (easier to see where the "magic number" comes from) and less error prone. The assembler will calculate the constant for you.

Answer (score 1):

for text mode you could use this simple procedure

```
clrscr proc
    mov ax,0003h
    int 10h 
    ret
endp
```

and call it in your program by

```
call clrscr
```

Comment: The problem is that he's not using text mode, and this will change video mode to text mode. He's also tried resetting the video mode to the one he's actually using, but this caused unwanted blinks.

Answer (score 0):

The next code works on msdos 5.0. It works on vga mode (640x480 pixels and a palette of 16 colors).

```
BORRARPANTALLAVGA:
;Erases the screen in graphic mode
;Input:
;CH: Background color.
    PUSH    AX
    PUSH    CX
    PUSH    DX
    PUSH    DI
    PUSH    ES
    MOV     DX,     3C4H
    MOV     AX,     0F02H
    OUT     DX,     AX
    MOV     DX,     3CEH
    MOV     AH,     CH
    XOR     AL,     AL
    OUT     DX,     AX
    MOV     AX,     0F01H
    OUT     DX,     AX
    MOV     CX,     19200
    XOR     DI,     DI
    MOV     AX,     0A000H
    MOV     ES,     AX
    CLD
    REP     STOSW
    MOV     DX,     3CEH
    MOV     AX,     1
    OUT     DX,     AX
    POP     ES
    POP     DI
    POP     DX
    POP     CX
    POP     AX
    RET
```

I hope that this could help.

Please, forgive my possible errors.

The code has been redited to include the corrections from Michael Petch. Thanks Michael.

If you need read some documentation, it can be read here:

[Online ebook about vga programming](http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/vgareg.htm)

Comment: You should explain this code, as it is it may not be useful for some to understand why this works. There is a bug in this code though. Your code assumes that the 4 bit planes are currently enabled which may or may not be the case. You really should make sure they are all enabled with `MOV  DX, 3C4H` `MOV AX, 0F02H` `OUT DX, AX`

Comment: As well you do an unusual thing to set CX. You multiply what happens to be in AX with the value 40. If you know the screen size is 640*480 then the number of WORDs needed to clear it will be 640*(480/8)/2 . Rather than do `MOV     BX, 40` `MUL     BX` `MOV     CX,     AX` you could replace it with `MOV CX, 640*(480/8)/2` .Your method happens to almost double the number of screen memory addresses that need to be cleared.