# How to clear Screen in x86 Graphical mode

Tags: x86

I tried using int 10h / ah = 06h with al = 00h to clear the entire window but after a few seconds everything just comes back again for some reason.

Am i missing something simple?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x86 Video mode Clear Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13979246) - an answer there recommends just zeroing all the bytes of video memory, but no answers say exactly why a BIOS call won't work, and don't explain your symptoms.

Comment: Did you write a DOS program that cleared the screen and then returned back to the DOS prompt immediately? Your question is lacking a lot of details to understand the exact nature of the problem or the context of the issue.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: BTW, there's a close reason that's specifically for lack of a [mcve] / debugging details.  I prefer that one when it's applicable.  If your close vote was the one that existed before I cast one, it sounds like that SO-specific close reason would fit even better than the more generic "needs more details", since that sounds like what you're commenting about.